# How to close all defined childform with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parent-child

- For assumption, there are more than 3 childforms as
  `Can_ListCandidate` and some other forms opened. Whenever I click a
  button, all `Can_ListCandidate` forms will be closed.

I've tried the code below but it did not work.

```
Can_ListCandidate frm = new Can_ListCandidate();

foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
{
    if (f == frm)
    {
        frm.Dispose();
        return;
    }
}
```

or

```
Can_ListCandidate frm = new Can_ListCandidate();

foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
{
    if (f is Can_ListCandidate)
    {
        frm.Dispose();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` is referential equality. I think you want to do `f is Can_ListCandidate`.

Comment: It might help then to post some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
{
        if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Can_ListCandidate))
        {
            frm.Dispose();
            //return;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (f.GetType() == typeof(Can_ListCandidate))
```